# How to disable updates in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

Often my laptop gets super slow because of regular windows 10 updates. It's very annoying. Is there a way to prevent automatic updates in Windows 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and also not at all recommended.

Your laptop should not get slow from windows updates in Windows 10, especially given the annual updates every half year that you obviously should install at some point. If you don't install these updates, yes, then your laptop will become slow.

That said, here's how you can disable windows update.

Go to your services and stop the Windows Update service, then open its properties and set the service to disabled.

There may also be a Windows Update process running, if so, kill that too. The process is there to make sure your computer restarts after an update. If windows update is installing an update, I suggest you to let it finish updating because otherwise, you may break windows update altogether which means you may need to reinstall windows completely if you ever want to upgrade to a newer version of windows.

Comment: Such a broken system. Linux doesn't turn your computer off in the middle of software build and fuck up your files. Why can't I just get a choice to disable this shit and turn it on when I want to? If turn it off, somehow it comes back on and then tells me it's going to restart my computer when I clearly do not want to. I never turn my computer off because when I turn in on, I start working. Stupid Microsoft. It's possible to delete the windows update files but they'll keep coming back. It's stupid really

Comment: @chx101 Please understand, this is a Q&A site, not a forum. Complaining will not help anyone. Secondly, if you follow my instructions in this answer you will completely disable windows update and it won't come on by itself. It it came on by itself, you did not execute the method properly.